# Gradle: exclude package from src/main when building a flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on configuration of android project using flavors. There are three flavors, two of them are using the same package from main source("src/main"), the third one needs this package to be excluded. Is there any way to exclude source from "main" using a particular flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java plugin adds src/main automatically to the java srcDir which implements interface [SourceDirectorySet](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html). However, this interface does not allow the removal of directories but only additions of it.
As a workaround you can:

1. Rename the shared code folder so it won't be included automatically (e.g. by placing the code in src/main under common/src/main or something similar)
2. Add a prepareSources task of type Copy that will copy all relevant sources under an alternative src/main folder (e.g. under $project.buildDir/src)
3. Make compileJava and processResources dependent on the new prepareSources task: 
   `compileJava.dependsOn prepareSources
   processResources.dependsOn prepareSources`
4. Add the new src directory to srcDir

While it may not be the optimal solution, this should do the work.